# Reading line by line from file and processing lines at same time?

Tags: python

Is there a way to read lines from a file at the same time as those lines are being processed. So the reading and processing would be done separate from each other. Whenever data is read it would give for processing, so that reading is always being done regardless of how fast the processing is.

Comment: You could do the reads on a separate thread and use a `threading.Queue` to pass the data to the main thread.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Speed improvement?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "at the same time". Let's assume you don't necessarily want to go down the rabbit hole of multiple threads, green threads or event-based code and that you just want to cleanly separate reading of the lines, filtering/processing those lines and consuming those lines in your actual business logic.

That can easily be achieved with iterators and generators (the latter being a special kind of iterable). The `file` object returned from an `open()` call being usable as iterator in itself makes this a lot easier.

Consider this simple chaining of generator expressions (which, sure enough, are a kind of iterable) that pre-filter the read lines:

```py
f = open('file-with-myriads-of-lines.txt', 'r')

# strip away trailing whitespace (including the newline)
lines_stripped = (line.rstrip() for line in f)

# remove trailing "#" comments (note: ignores potential quoting)
lines_without_comment = (line.partition('#')[0] for line in lines_stripped)

# remove remaining surrounding whitespace
lines_cleaned = (line.strip() for line in lines_without_comment)

# filter out (now) empty lines
lines_with_content = (line for line in lines_cleaned if line)

for line in lines_with_content:
    # your business logic goes here
    print("Line: {}".format(line))
```

While you could have combined some of that filtering / mangling into one generator expression or put it inside the for loop, this way the tasks are cleanly separated and you could easily mix and match by reordering, removing or adding more generators to the chain.

This also only reads and processes each line on demand, whenever one is consumed in the business logic for loop (which could also be tucked away in a separate function somewhere else). It **does not read all the lines upfront** and it also **does not create intermediate lists** with all the intermediate results. This is in contrast to list comprehensions, which are written with square brackets instead of parentheses.

Of course you can also give each unit of processing a name in the form of a function, to increase readability, encapsulation and maintainability:

```py
def strip_trailing_whitespace(iterable):
    return (line.rstrip() for line in iterable)

def remove_trailing_comments(iterable):
    return (line.partition('#')[0] for line in iterable)

# ...


def preprocess_lines(iterable):

    iterable = strip_trailing_whitespace(iterable)
    iterable = remove_trailing_comments(iterable)
    # ...

    return iterable


def business_logic(iterable):
    for line in iterable:
        # your business logic here
        print("Line: {}".format(line))


def main():
    with open('file-with-myriads-of-lines.txt', 'r') as f:
        iterable = preprocess_lines(f)
        business_logic(iterable)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And if your pre-processing of each line gets more complex than what is usable inside a generator expression, you can simply expand this to a custom generator function using the `yield` statement or expression:

```py
def remove_trailing_comments(iterable):
    """Remove #-comments that are outside of double-quoted parts."""

    for line in iterable:
        pos = -1
        while True:
            pos = line.find('#', pos + 1)
            if pos < 0:
                break    # use whole line

            if line[:pos].count('"') % 2 == 0:
                # strip starting from first "#" that's not inside quotes
                line = line[:pos]
                break

        yield line
```

Everything else remains the same.